# Unable to delete emails because mailbox is full

Tags: email, imap, apple-mail, email-client

I just realized my email mailbox is full. (I'm using IMAP) I looked at my emails and saw two with a size of 21MB. I wanted to delete them but whenever I try to delete I get this message from sever

> UID COPY: Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full)

I think that's the case because all mail clients I am using are trying to move the mail into a "Trash" folder, and moving consist of "copying the mail and then deleting the original mail" in imap. (That means that my mailbox would need to store additional 21MB for a short time)

I tried it using the Mac Mail, the iOS Mail and Roundcube Webmail 0.9.5. Is there any way to delete the email without moving it first?

Comment: Use the shorcut to permenantly delete the email so you have remove to 'copy and delete" other emails.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure where I should find this shortcut? In Mac Mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the option in Mac OS X Mail to delete a message without moving it to the trash folder:

You have to uncheck "Move deleted messages to Trash mailbox" under Preferences > Accounts > Mailbox Behaviors then the mails are directly deleted.

[image]